# Kmemsize problems in VPS even when there is about 500MB free mem

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, memory

I have a site hosted on a Plesk VPS with 512MB memory and keep on getting kmemsize in "black zone" QoS errors. The soft limit of kmemsize is 12,288,832 and hard limit is 13,517,715.

The definition Virtuozzo gives is: Size of unswappable memory, allocated by the operating system kernel.

What's eating up the kmemsize? Is there any way to reconfigure and increase the kmemsize? The servers barely have any load or processing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is eaten by processes (and threads). Do you have lots of processes/threads running? And concerning increasing it - well, it's up to the hoster, you can't do anything.